# How can i set a color to the last inserted record in Android?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I have created an activity which contains a button. I also set an `OnClickListener`. When the button is pressed, 2 thing are happening. First one, i insert some data into a Mysql database like this:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    parameters.put("username", userNameText.getText().toString());
    parameters.put("score", String.valueOf(correct));
    return parameters;
}
```

And second, i start a new activity. I the new activity, i simply display the database records like this:

```
JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("statistics");
for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject student = users.getJSONObject(i);

    String userName = student.getString("username");
    String score = student.getString("score");

    statistics.append(userName + " " + score + " \n");
}
```

So, when the button is pressed, the records are inserted into the database and the new activity has started. So, how can i set red color to the last inserted record, when the new activity has started?

Comment: Your last record should be JSONObject last_object = users.getJSONObject((users.length) - 1);

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can i set the color red, only to the last one record?

Comment: Are you setting last recoed to textView or something else

Comment: I have a `TextView` named `statistics` in which i append all the records. I need only the last one to be red. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try something like this:

I did not run this code but you can use this code as a pseudo code :

```
String first_data;
String last_data;

JSONArray users = response.getJSONArray("statistics");
for (int i = 0; i < (users.length()-2); i++) {
    JSONObject student = users.getJSONObject(i);

    String userName = student.getString("username");
    String score = student.getString("score");

    first_data = userName + " " + score + " \n";

}

JSONObject last_student = users.getJSONObject(users.length()-1);
String last_userName = last_student .getString("username");
String last_score = last_student .getString("score");

last_data = last_userName + " " + last_score + " \n";

statistics.append(Html.fromHtml(first_data + "<font color="red">" +last_record +"</font>"));
```

Comment: Thanks you! With your updated code works, the last record is now red but there is an issue. Although there exist many records in the database, in the activity are displayed only 2 and not the last 2. Every time the activity starts, the same 2 records are displayed. Why that?
"<font color="red">" must be "<font color='red'>"

Comment: And the `String last_userName = student.getString("username");` must be `String last_userName = last_student.getString("username");`. Same for the second.

Comment: I changed the code but still have the same problem. Only 2 records are displayed. The same record every time. What can i do?

Comment: @Alex M. ,right now I am not able to run this code.So , I will tell you after running the code

Comment: I figure it out! I added this inside the loop `statistics.append(Html.fromHtml(first_data + "<br>"));` and this outside the loop `statistics.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>" + last_data + "</font>"));` and it works. Thanks!